# simple multiple second countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have **several** `<span class="timer">342</span>` with different values (**seconds**).
I want to **countdown all of them** and thought I could do something like:

```
            $('.timer').ready(function() {
                timer = setInterval(function() {
                    sec = $('.timer').text();
                    $('.timer').text(--sec);
                    if (sec == 0) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        location.href = 'accounts.php';
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
```

The error is, Javascript gets confused because of more than 1 object of `.timer` or something and generates weird values for the spans.

When the first timer hits zero it should reload. Using jQuery.
The **number of spans is not fixed**.
I'd really like to **keep it simple and don't use an extra plugin** or big script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ready` is only used for the `document` and marks the point when the DOM is fully parsed.  Within this function, `this` refers to the document. I'd write it another way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('.timer').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var countdown = parseInt($this.text()) - 1;

            $this.text(countdown);
            if (countdown == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                location.href = 'accounts.php';
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Important:

1. Use `.each` to iterate through every timer
2. Use `parseInt` to get an integer from a string

Here's an <kbd>**[Example-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTXE2/7/)**</kbd> that works.

Comment: In the fiddle, only the first span decreases. I need all spans to decrease 1 by second.

Comment: Ah, I see you got it yourself ;)

Comment: 'ight! I'm gonna adept your `parseInt` part and give you +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it myself.
THIS really works ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCdYR/) ):

```
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                $('.timer').each(function(index, el) {
                    sec = $(el).text();
                    $(el).text(--sec);
                    if (sec == 0) {
                        location.href = 'accounts.php';
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
```